# Tables must be fixed in migrations

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database-migration

I have a test task to build an app, and one of the requirements is **"Tables must be fixed in migrations"**. What does it exactly mean?
I use MongoDB and Node.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that you need to use a migration script to operate some database operations.

It aims to maintain the database schema or any data in the db up to the code version.

> With each release, we should be able to do a fast, reliable database update without compromising existing data and have a possibility of rollback in case of the worst-case scenario.

This is from an sql article about [database schema migrations](https://medium.com/patrik-bego/database-schema-migrations-with-nodejs-de9d9090b177)

Here is an article about [mongoDB automated migration](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-automate-database-migrations-in-mongodb-d6b68efe084e/)